# Can ffmpeg read gif image(s)?

Tags: ffmpeg, images, gif

I have a lot of similar gif images and I want to make a movie in that way:

```
ffmpeg -i img%06d.gif -c:v libx264 mymovie.mp4
```

If all images are JPEG everything works fine. But GIFs are stuck with message:

```
img%06d.gif: No such file or directory
Conversion failed!
```

Is it possible to process gifs with `ffmpeg`?

There is about 30 GB of gifs so conversion to jpeg isn't an option.

---

Yep. Another case is solved.

`ffmpeg` treat GIFs as movies, not a single images. Always.
Therefore we have to `concat` videostreams instead of batching the frames. Here is the solution:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c:v libx264 mymovie.mp4
```

filelist.txt accordingly to the [ffmpeg manual](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join%2C%20merge)%20media%20files#samecodec) should be the next format:

```
# some comment
file '/path/img000001.gif'
file '/path/img000002.gif'
file '/path/img000003.gif'
. . . . .
```

Comment: Could that be a bug? If you run `ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%06d.gif -c:v libx264 mymovie.mp4`, does that work?

Comment: [image2 @ 0x80647a420] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
%06d.gif: could not find codec parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg treat GIFs as movies, not a single images. Always. Therefore we have to concat videostreams instead of batching the frames. Here is the solution:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c:v libx264 mymovie.mp4
```

filelist.txt accordingly to the ffmpeg manual should be the next format:

```
# some comment
file '/path/img000001.gif'
file '/path/img000002.gif'
file '/path/img000003.gif'
. . . . .
```

Comment: If you have lots of files, with Bash or Zsh you could do: `ffmpeg -f concat -i <(for f in /path/*.gif; do echo "file '$f'"; done) -c:v libx264 output.mp4`